# Am getting response from server after sending user name and password , but i can't able to validate response in Login page?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting a response from a server after sending user name and password but I am not able to validate the response in Login page.

I am getting the below response.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:urlStr parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"String%@",urlStr);
    _responceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *localError = nil;
    if ([_responceString isEqual:@"fail"]) {
        NSLog(@"Do Nothing");
    } else {
        NSDictionary *studData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&localError];
        NSLog(@"response == %@", studData);

    _userDetailsString = [studData valueForKey:@"category"];
    _messageArray=[_userDetailsString valueForKey:@"Message"];
    _usernameArray=[_userDetailsString valueForKey:@"First_Name"];
    _resultArray=[_userDetailsString valueForKey:@"result"];





       //  _resultArray = [[studData valueForKey:@"category"] valueForKey:@"result"];

         NSLog(@" value is %@", _resultArray);


if ([_resultArray isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
                 NSLog(@"response == %@", _resultArray);




          [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
             _objHomeviewcontroller=(HomeViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:_objHomeviewcontroller animated:YES];

         }
         else
         {
             [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];

             UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message: @"invalid data" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                              [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                              }]];

                            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


         }
```

The response:

```
response == {
    category =     (
                {
            "First_Name" = Sahithi;
            "Last_Name" = L;
            "branch_id" = "05/10/2018 13:11:27  PM";
            result = Success;
            roles = Parent;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Include some relevant code where your problem lies. E.g how did you receive this response in code.

Comment: You are getting a result `Success`. Does that mean that the validation was successful?

Comment: how to validate to go  next page .

Comment: `valueForKey` applied to an array returns an array, so `isEqualToString` will always fail. It's unclear what you are going to accomplish. Please learn to read the response, it's very simple: `()` is array, `{}` is dictionary.

Comment: from the response structure you have pasted, Your category is an array of dictionary. so you need to get the first object from array and then do the code that you are doing now.

Comment: NSArray *array = [studData valueForKey:@"category"] will return array. Get the first object of the array by NSDictionary *dictionary = [array firstObject] and then do [dictionary valueForKey:@"First_Name"] and [dictionary valueForKey:@"result"] to get the login details

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps. You are looking for the result property. If it is equal to `Success` you can move to the next view controller.

```
If( [[[[studData valueForKey:@"category"] firstObject] objectForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString: @"Success"]) {

    // goto the next view controller
    _objHomeviewcontroller=(HomeViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_objHomeviewcontroller animated:YES];

} else { // goto another view controller}
```

Comment: Please don't adopt bad habits and suggest `valueForKey` unless you can explain why the KVC functionality is needed. Modern (for many years) recommended ObjC syntax is `studData[@"category"]` or at least `[studData objectForKey:@"category"]`